# mobile user agent detection with htaccess

Tags: android, ios, .htaccess

I want to redirect ipad/iphone and android users to a specific page that tells the user to get the app or continue to the main site.

I thought I could do this with htaccess:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|ipad|iphone|ipod" [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/getapp [L,R=302]
```

For example a user wants to go to http://www.example.com from an Android or iOS device. I want to redirect that user to the getapp page. In this getapp page are the links to get the app (from Play or iTunes) and it has a link to go to the main site (www.example.com) if you just want to skip the download of the app.

But if I put this code inside htaccess I get `This web page has a redirect loop`. Maybe htaccess is the wrong way about this. What is a better way to do this?

Comment: Question isn't very clear. What do you mean by `That just puts me in a loop`?

Comment: @anubhava updated question, hopefully that helps...

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to redirect to `/getapp` if you're already there. Try excluding that URI:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|ipad|iphone|ipod" [NC]
RewriteRule !^getapp http://www.example.com/getapp [L,R=302]
```

---

To allow an optout after a user visits the getapp page, you'll need to persist a cookie or something:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|ipad|iphone|ipod" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !app-optout
RewriteRule !^getapp http://www.example.com/getapp [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|ipad|iphone|ipod" [NC]
RewriteRule ^getapp - [CO=app-optout:1:www.example.com]
```

So here, you only redirect to `/getapp` if there is *no* "app-optout" cookie. Once there, you set the opt out so that they don't get redirected there again if they navigate out of the getapp page.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but you are not already there. I've tried to clarify my question.

Comment: @Tom if you want to track the user "opting out" of getting the app, then you need something more persistent than the URI

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|ipad|iphone|ipod" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!getapp).*$ http://www.example.com/getapp [L,R=302,NC]
```

Comment: Same problem using this

Comment: Do you have another .htaccess anywhere in your DOCUMENT_ROOT or any other existing rule?